# Same preposition twice in a row

Tags: prepositions, repetition

Does it sound OK to a native ear when a preposition is repeated like this?

*I want to move in in the first week of August.* – where the first *in* is part of *move in* and the second *in* is part of *in the first week*.

Would you try to reconstruct the sentence to avoid the repetition? Would it make a difference whether you're writing vs. speaking?

Answer (score 2):

In speech, there would be no problem. The first 'in' would receive considerable emphasis, while the second would hardly register, so the jarring duplication would not occur.

Written, it does look very awkward. You could substitute 'during' for the temporal usage. But if you are quoting someone's words, you have to choose looking awkward rather than being infelicitous.